# Terraform append string to for_each each.key

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to append some text to the Name tag for each resource created. I want the name to be the 'key' name + "a string"

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "commerce_vpc_pc" {
for_each      = local.requester_vpcs

  peer_vpc_id   = data.aws_vpc.tf_commerce_vpc.id
  vpc_id        = each.value.vpc_id
  auto_accept   = true

  tags = {
    Name = [each.key]+"_pc_commerce"
  }
}
```

This give the error:

```
│ Error: Invalid operand
│ 
│   on main.tf line 34, in resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "commerce_vpc_pc":
│   34:     Name = [each.key]+"-to-commerce_vpc"
│ 
│ Unsuitable value for right operand: a number is required.
```

which makes sense.  However is it possible to append some text to the each.key key?

Comment: `"${each.key}_pc_commerce"`!?

Comment: @luk2302 exactly what i wanted, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @70ny I wanted to keep it simple and thought the content was enough as the other code was irrelevant in to the issue being faced. Plus it was my very first post so could've been a bit gentler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "commerce_vpc_pc" {
  for_each      = local.requester_vpcs

  peer_vpc_id   = data.aws_vpc.tf_commerce_vpc.id
  vpc_id        = each.value.vpc_id
  auto_accept   = true

  tags = {
    Name = "${each.key}_pc_commerce"
  }
}
```

See this another example of provisioning a customer gateway.

```
################################################################################
# Customer Gateways
################################################################################

resource "aws_customer_gateway" "this" {
  for_each = var.customer_gateways

  bgp_asn     = each.value["bgp_asn"]
  ip_address  = each.value["ip_address"]
  device_name = lookup(each.value, "device_name", null)
  type        = "ipsec.1"

  tags = merge(
    { Name = "${var.name}-${each.key}" },
    var.tags,
    var.customer_gateway_tags,
  )
}
```

Comment: Works as a charm!